# Python (DFS): Please explain this clearly to me: stack.extend(graph[vertex] - visited)

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I am new to Python and decided to practice algorithms to gain a strong foundation. I am having difficulty understanding this particular line in the code that implements DFS: `stack.extend(graph[vertex] - visited)`. Does it mean that graph[vertex] contains all the vertices present in the graph and this line removes the most recently visited vertex, and returns the remaining unvisited list of vertices in the graph? Please find source of code [here under connected component](http://eddmann.com/posts/depth-first-search-and-breadth-first-search-in-python/). Thanks!!

Comment: Without actually looking at the code, I would assume it means "add all elements that are in `graph[vertex]`, but not in `visited`, to `stack`."

Comment: Adding to what @JohnGordon said, the code in question is adding the unexplored neighbors of `vertex` to the stack of vertices to visit in the future.

Comment: Thanks @ljeabmreosn!!

Answer (score 1):

I'll paste in the code in your link for all to see:

```
def dfs(graph, start):
    visited, stack = set(), [start]
    while stack:
        vertex = stack.pop()
        if vertex not in visited:
            visited.add(vertex)
            stack.extend(graph[vertex] - visited)
    return visited
```

**What's happening in this code:**

With the given vertex called `start`, we are adding all of its adjacent vertices, represented by `graph[vertex]`, in order to check if we have already traveled to that vertex. If not, we need to add that vertex to the set called `visited` and extend `stack` with all of its adjacent vertices. Next, we pop an element from the now-extended `stack` and go through the same process of checking until there are no more elements remaining.

**Answer to the question:**

I suspect that the `- visited` portion of `stack.extend(graph[vertex] - visited)` might have thrown you off. Here, `- visited` does not affect the functionality of the code but it helps in optimizing the code. This is only to prevent double-checking of the vertices that we have already visited, thus subtracting `visited` from `graph[vertex]`. Lastly, I'd note that `graph` should be a dictionary of sets (not lists) for the subtraction to work without throwing an error.